# Is the existence of a linear operator between two vectors always possible?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, question-verification

I have some questions to gain insigth on some core concepts of linear algebra:

Supose $V(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is a complex vector space, $\{v,u\}\in V$ are arbitrary distinct vectors with $v≠0$. Can we always find a linear operator $\tau:V\rightarrow V$ such that $\tau(v)=u$?

If it is the case, can we always find such an operator on a real vector space?
Does this implies that every linear transformation has an eigenvalue?

Comment: Why would this imply that every linear transformation has an eigenvalue?

Comment: For the first part, split into cases (according to whether $\{\vec v, \vec u\}$ are linearly dependent or not.  If they are independent, extend to a basis.

Comment: One needs to assume $v$ is nonzero, unless the case happens to be $u$ is also zero.  A linear transformation on a real vector space may have no real eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is always possible to find a map such that $v \mapsto u$, except when $v = 0$ because a linear transformation always maps the zero vector to itself. Indeed, you can take $v$ as the first basis vector of $V$ and maps it to $u$, such that the vector $u$ will appear as the first column of the matrix representation of $\tau$.

However, the eigenvalues of such a map are not necessarily real; indeed, the case $v = (1,0), u = (0,1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are linked by the linear operator $\tau = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, whose eigenvalues are $\pm i$.

If you want another concrete example, you can take $\tau = \frac{uv^\dagger}{\|v\|^2}$ for instance. The same map works for the real case when replacing $v^\dagger$ with $v^T$. Rotations constitute good candidates too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was very helpful.

Comment: Shouldn’t the $u$ vector on your example be $u=(0;-1)$?

Comment: @SimónFlavioIbañez   
$$
\tau v = 
   \begin{pmatrix}
      0 & -1 \\
      1 & 0 
   \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}
      1 \\
      0
   \end{pmatrix}
= 
   \begin{pmatrix}
      0 \\
      1 
   \end{pmatrix}
= u
$$